# How can I get rid of these thick and pixelated outlines?

Tags: borderlands-2

As you can see in this screenshot, there are these thick black outlines all over the place:

[image: Heavy black lines]

I've attempted:

- Changing resolution
- Using fullscreen or windowed
- Upgrade FPS to maximum
- turn sync on
- turn up anisotropic filtering.

The issue continues regardless of these settings changes.

What's the cause and how can I change it?

Comment: I believe that's the game's drawing style.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18528/black-outlines-in-borderlands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The black outlines are part of the art style of Borderlands, most of what you see on your screenshot is intentional.

The only way to get rid of the pixelation is to enable antialiasing (FXAA option in the video menu).

I'd also recommend to use the lastest driver to deal with any graphical issues.

The outlines look a bit thinner on my computer, the following screenshot is with FXAA enabled:

[image]

Comment: You can disable it via config file.

Answer (score 7):

In WillowEngine.ini, find this line:

```
DefaultPostProcessName=WillowEngineMaterials.WillowScenePostProcess
```

To turn off the shader, you need to make adjustments to the line —
namely, remove both instances of the word “Willow,” so it looks like
this:

```
DefaultPostProcessName=EngineMaterials.ScenePostProcess
```

Source:http://www.gamefront.com/how-to-improve-borderlands-2-with-ini-file-tweaks/

Comment: Cool find. That's an excellent article.